# Slow Video play in mobile devices

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video

i have implemented video play functionality using html5 video tag.In web video play instantly but in mobile it takes to 15-20 seconds to play video over 3g/Wifi network

i have searched for this issue and tried partial content request script in php but partial content request not working in browser.
we have using **ffmpeg** for video encoding and **akamai** as cdn.

```
ffmpeg -i '20102707.mp4' -y -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vprofile baseline -preset slow -b:v 158035 -r 12/1 -vf "scale=480:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -acodec libfaac -b:a 18320 -ar 16000 -ac 2 '20102707_VIDEO_MEDIUM_H264.mp4' 2>&1
```

i have tired different bit rate and frame rate for video encoding but all taking more time to play

Any idea?

Comment: Add `-movflags faststart` for the output.

Comment: yes i already tried this as ..
ffmpeg -i '20102707.mp4' -y -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vprofile baseline -preset slow -b:v 250k -r 15/1 -vf "scale=320:trunc(ow/a/2)*2"  -movflags faststart -acodec aac -strict -2 -b:a 48k -ar 16000 -ac 1 '20102707_H264_1.mp4' 2>&1 is it right?